# Find what settings influence a given Pylint message

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

When Pylint warns me about something, how can I know what settings it's applying? And what section of `.pylintrc` this setting goes in?

For example:

- `Used builtin function 'map'. Using a list comprehension can be clearer. (bad-builtin)` is because `bad-functions` in `[BASIC]` contains `map`.
- `Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)` is conditional on `docstring-min-length` in `[BASIC]`.
- `invalid-name` obeys several `[BASIC]` settings: `variable-rgx`, `method-rgx`, `module-rgx`, etc.

I expected to find this information in the [Pylint documentation](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but it generally doesn't provide this information. For example, there's no link from [the documentation of `missing-docstring` or `invalid-names`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#basic-checker-messages) to the [applicable options](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#basic-checker-options). With `bad-builtin`, the information is easy to find, but only because it's from a [specific extension](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/extensions.html#deprecated-builtins-checker). The [Pylint message wiki](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/) has explanations about what the message means, but not what brought it up. The comments in `pylint --generate-rcfile` don't relate the settings to warning codenames either (nothing there explains that e.g. `bad-functions` influences the `bad-builtin` message).

The reason I'm asking this is that in many cases, Pylint's conventions don't match my project's needs and conventions, and I want to tune it rather than ignore specific instances or ignore messages wholesale (so I'm not looking for `disable=`!). So how do I find what to tune?

Answer (score 0):

*How do I find what to tune?*

So it seems like you're asking about how you can determine the combination of factors that lead to a pylint message being raised. Using the `bad-builtin` example, a warning message that is not listed at all in the `.pylintrc`, a helpful verbose message would be:

> `bad-builtin`: `Used builtin function 'map'. Using a list comprehension can be clearer.`
>
> ---> `(Hypothetical) VERBOSE OUTPUT`:
>
> `bad-builtin` was raised because the `bad-functions` setting in your `.pylintrc` under the `[BASIC]` section contains the function `map`. If you want to "tune" this behavior look here.

**Short answer**: I am not sure this exists.

When you run `pylint my_file.py` the first thing it should tell you is the configuration file it is using. From there, you want to find the `.pylintrc` in use or else you want to create it. Otherwise it will be using the default configuration. If pylint does not tell you what config you are using you can figure out your current pylintrc configuration by running something like:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile &> output.txt
```

When you inspect output.txt it should look like this [example pylintrc](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/blob/master/.pylintrc). It is organized into different categories. You can get more info on this without generating an rcfile by running `pylint --long-help`. The sections include:

```
[MASTER]
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
[REPORTS]
[BASIC]
[ELIF]
[TYPECHECK]
[FORMAT]
[MISCELLANEOUS]
[VARIABLES]
[LOGGING]
[SIMILARITIES]
[SPELLING]
[IMPORTS]
[DESIGN]
[CLASSES]
[EXCEPTIONS]
```

I am not sure what you mean by, "The Pylint message wiki has explanations about what the message means, but not what brought it up." When I run pylint on a file or in a code base it tells me exactly where the offending line is.

Then I usually either:

- Fix the warning
- Disable the warning
- Modify the `.pylintrc` to meet my needs

If you want to tune a specific message type but you are not sure how to do so, then I think you are right that is something that could be better documented. The question: `Is XYZ warning message 'tunable'?` Or is the only option to fix OR disable? [This page lists the pylint features](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html?highlight=bad-builtin) but I do not see anything about bad built-in, for example, let alone the options that are available to apply to a message type.

UPDATE: I am not sure what version of pylint you are on, but it looks like the `bad-builtin` was [specifically addressed in pylint version 1.6](http://%20https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/c3e2d5e03d0122e544183f1c2c66ef68066283c8/doc/whatsnew/1.6.rst#other-changes). I was going to say we should look at what is going on in the actual source code to generate this message, but I think that requires figuring out what version of pylint you are on first, then digging into the code, then figuring out how to tune it? I agree that the docs can be more clear on how to tune specific warnings:

> The bad-builtin check was moved into an extension.
>
> The check was complaining about used builtin functions which were
>   supposed to not be used. For instance, map and filter were falling
>   into this category, since better alternatives can be used, such as
>   list comprehensions. But the check was annoying, since using map or
>   filter can have its use cases and as such, we decided to move it to an
>   extension check instead. It can now be enabled through
>   --load-plugins=pylint.extensions.bad_builtin.

Comment: I know about `pylint --generate-rcfile` (I should have mentioned it in my question), but it doesn't help any more than the other sources I looked at. For example, nothing in there relates “Used builtin function 'map'. Using a list comprehension can be clearer. (bad-builtin)” to the `bad-functions` setting.

Comment: Ahh, so you're not interested in the offending line in the file you are linting - you are interested in the combination of settings in the `.pylintrc` that lead to that message being raised?

Comment: Obviously when Pylint tells me it doesn't like something, I look at the offending line. But in many cases, I want Pylint to understand that _this type of usage_ is fine (given my project's use case and style guide), not just _this specific occurrence_. Often that goes through a setting, for example I've set `bad-functions` to a value that doesn't include `map`. The question is how to find this setting, other than trial and error or hoping that someone has asked about that specific setting on SO before.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely get what you are asking now. Kind of like a `"pylint traceback"` that can be enabled with something like `pylint --verbose` (kind of like `pytest --verbose`) or `pylint --traceback` to show you the combination of factors that lead to a warning or error message being raised. I am not sure if that documentation exists, but it doesn't look like anything like verbose exists.